# Sails js should not return password and email

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to create CRUD app in sails js, and i am able to post data to my DB what i noticed is when i insert data on success sails return whole object. But if we don't want certain fields in response then how can we restrict it. Please help thanks.

```
module.exports = {
attributes : {
    username : {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    password : {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    email : {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
},
toJson: function() {
    var obj = this.toObject();
    delete obj.password;
    return obj;
},

beforeCreate: function(attribute, callback) {
    console.log(attribute.password);
    require('bcrypt').hash(attribute.password, 10, function(err, encryptedPassword) {   
        sails.log(err);
        attribute.password = encryptedPassword;
        sails.log(encryptedPassword);
        callback();
    });
}
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@arbuthnott is partly correct above -- you do need `toJSON` rather than `toJson` -- but more importantly, the function needs to go *inside the `attributes` dictionary*, since it is an instance method:

```
attributes : {
    username : {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    password : {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    email : {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the responses through sails default REST api for models runs them through `.toJSON` before returning, so you are doing this the right way.

However, you may have a case issue, like you should define `.toJSON` with uppercase instead of `.toJson`. Try making that switch and see if it solves your problem.

---

UPDATE

Sounds like this is not solving your issue. The sails docs from [here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json) say:

> The real power of toJSON relies on the fact every model instance sent out via res.json is first passed through toJSON. Instead of writing custom code for every controller action that uses a particular model (including the "out of the box" blueprints), you can manipulate outgoing records by simply overriding the default toJSON function in your model. You would use this to keep private data like email addresses and passwords from being sent back to every client.

That sounds pretty explicitly like what we are trying to do, so maybe this is a sails bug. Perhaps it applies to `find`, but not `create`. Is that password returned when simply finding an existing user?

If you must, a sure way around this would be to override the default create action in your UserController:

```
create: function(req, res) {
    User.create(req.body).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }
        // explicitly call your own toJSON() to be sure
        return res.send(user.toJSON());
    });
},
```

This isn't ideal, especially if you have many model properties you want to hide in many api calls. But it will get the job done.

Comment: Thanx for reply arbuthnott, but changing it to uppercase also not working.

Comment: posted an update, for what it's worth. Not sure why the casing didn't solve it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> password: { type: 'string', required: true, protected: true }

`protected:true` is now deprecated on sails v1.0

You can use instead of that [customToJSON](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson)

```
customToJSON: function() {
  // Return a shallow copy of this record with the password and ssn removed.
  return _.omit(this, ['password', 'ssn'])
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me, I'm trying to `parseInt` a field, it seems to never run my `customToJSON` do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
password: { type: 'string', required: true, protected: true }
```

You can do this also.